# H264 AVC codec Baseline@L3.1 vs High@L4.2

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-quality, codec, h.264

When I convert a video with `ffmpeg`, and use `mediaInfo` to review the metadata, I see the followings for the video codec:

```
Format : AVC 
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
Format profile : Baseline@L3.1 
Format settings : 1 Ref Frames
```

Whereas for some other videos, `mediaInfo` shows this:

```
Format : AVC 
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
Format profile : High@L4.2 
Format settings : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
```

What are the differences between these two profiles and settings? Do they have any effects on the compression ratio/file sizes? Any pros/cons? My goal is to reduce the video file sizes at much as possible with negligible quality degradation.

Comment: More ref frames = better compression. Higher profile = better compression.

Comment: How about quality? Encoding execution time?